# HTML Appstore link and logo appears broken in the emails

Tags: html, css

I created an apple store link to an App from tools.applemediaservices.com and embedded it in an HTML which I use it in an Email - Below is the a tag.

```
<a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/symphony-secure-communications/id1098963705?itsct=apps_box_badge&amp;itscg=30200" style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 13px; width: 250px; height: 83px;"><img src="https://tools.applemediaservices.com/api/badges/download-on-the-app-store/black/en-us?size=250x83&amp;releaseDate=1465171200&h=79f9b0d11830b0975c496e1c6812d49c" alt="Download on the App Store" style="border-radius: 13px; width: 250px; height: 83px;"></a>
```

The logo appears ok in the browser but when I test in the browser but only displays alt text in emails.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not support svg image format, so for displaying it you should host somewhere png version of appstore badge to display it inside of the email. The easiest way to host this image is Amazon s3 bucket.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**Please apply this code**

```html
   <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/symphony-secure-communications/id1098963705?itsct=apps_box_badge&amp;itscg=30200"
      style="display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 13px; width: 250px; height: 83px;">
      <img src="https://apple-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/media-badges/download-on-the-app-store/black/en-us.svg"
         alt="Download on the App Store" style="border-radius: 13px; width: 250px; height: 83px;">
   </a>
```